# Modify TRIAC-based light dimmer for lower current

Tags: led, triac, dimmer

I have bought a commercial Solera-branded light dimmer, model ERP31LED, which is according to the manufacturer designed to dim lights at 230V between 3W and 250W.

When set to the minimum, the three 3W Ikea SOLHETTA LED lights on the ceiling begin to behave erratically, which I think it's due to the real load getting too close to the minimum.

Would there be any way to reduce the minimum load required? Reducing the maximum load is not a problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTZoTX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome! What’s the holding current listed in the triac’s datasheet?

Comment: @winny thanks! The datasheet for the BTB04-600SL lists Iₕ at a maximum of 15mA, with a Iₜ=100mA

Comment: LED lights very rarely work as expected with dimmers. They do make "dimmable" LED lights now, but you should check if yours is one.

Comment: @Hearth they are Ikea Solhetta, which are sold as dimmable.

Comment: 15 mA * 230 V = 3.45 W. It's not that simple but a back-of-the-envelope sanity check. Your average dimmer is limited in how low it can go by said holding current and to a lesser degree the triggering circuitry. You can probably find a different triac with lower holding current and replace the one in your dimmer, but at this point, it's probably cheaper and simpler to get a different dimmer.

Comment: Thanks @winny. Will attempt to find a different one with a dedicated neutral connection and no minimum load.

Comment: add a load, like a nitelite, a resistor, or somehting. I've had luck with an old AC-DC adapter that uses a heavy-ish transformer, which counter-balances the caps used in the led drivers to present a more resistive-looking load that can dim down better.